# capture strings between commas without the surrounding square braces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string input like var `[apple, cherry, banana]`.

When I try to match just the strings that are between the commas, I can get:

```
str.match(/(.*?[^\]|\[|(, )])/g)
```

captures all of the letters separately and also a comma. How can I get the whole string between the commas and also not capture the comma-space combination?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using character classes correctly. http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

Comment: It is for me so sad that you get people that just downvote questions instead of helping people out. For me it is just plain rude...

Comment: Why don't you trim the brackets and then split by `\s*,\s*` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\[)(\s*(?<str>[A-Za-z0-9]+)\s*,?)+(?=\])
```

(?<=...) = Scan before, but don't include

(?=....) = Scan ahead, but don't include

(?<...> = Named group.

You can then scan through the "str" group to get all the data.

Comment: FYI there is no lookbehinds nor named groups in javascript's regex flavor